# Can not reference System.data Error when creating project

Tags: visual-studio, reference, coded-ui-tests

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise to generate Coded UI Tests. Things have been working well until this morning. When I attempt to create a new Solution/Project, I am given the following error:

[image]

I am then able finish loading the project. However, I see another issue in solution explorer:
[image]

Note that there is no path given for the selected reference. If I try to remove it/add it back as a reference manually, I still do not see a path or version. I have tried the following:

- Selected different .Net framework versions when creating the solution/project
- Tried different project types: Window Forms, Class Library
- Repaired visual studio
- Repaired .Net Framework 4.6.1

So far I have been unable to make the error go away. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to resolve this issue. I ended up performing a reinstall of the OS/Visual Studio to get things working again.